# How to create trigger functions?

Tags: postgresql

How to create triggers?
I found an article on PostgreSQL's official website, but I couldn't understand what `spj`, `trim` and `ns` mean. Help me, please.

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_s_before_del () RETURNS trigger AS ' 
BEGIN 
if (select count(*) from spj a where trim(a.ns)=trim(OLD.ns))>0
then delete from spj where trim(spj.ns)=trim(OLD.ns); 
end if;
return OLD;
END; 
' LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

- `spj` is a table name
- `a` is an alias given to a table,
- `ns` is a column name in spj table,
- `trim` is a PostgreSQL buil-in function.

Answer (score 0):

to define a trigger, first we need a special kind of function which returns TRIGGER;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "myTriggerFunction"() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    myVal BOOLEAN = TRUE;
BEGIN
    myVal = ( OLD."myField" > NEW."myField" );

    IF myVal THEN
        INSERT INTO "sampleRelatedTable"
            ( "id", "someField_old", "someField_new" )
        VALUES
            ( OLD."id", OLD."myField", NEW."myField" )
        ;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

since our "Trigger Procedure" is ready, we can attach it to the table;

```
CREATE TRIGGER "myTrigger"
    UPDATE ON "myTable"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "myTriggerFunction"()
;
```

now our trigger is ready. it will trigger "myTriggerFunction" when a record in "myTable" is updated.

for detailed information refer to docs;

TRIGGER PROCEDURES : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html
CREATE TRIGGER : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Using those dreaded quoted identifiers is a sure way to get into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: i see your point. i always quote object names and leave variable names in functions as they are not going to be referenced from another place.